# SSRS Column Visibility by top two Date

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

We have SSRS Report with Date as Column Group, we are currently using following Express in Column Visibility to display Last Two Days Data

```
=IIF(Fields!FieldDate.Value > DateAdd("d",-2,Today), false, true)
```

this is working fine when data having both the date, i.e. today and yesterday.

But how can we display last two day's data, i mean if there are no data available for today's date then it should display yesterday and day before yesterday's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking against the **MAX** date in your data instead of the current date?

```
=IIF(Fields!FieldDate.Value > DateAdd("d",-2, MAX(Fields!FieldDate.Value, "DataSet") ), false, true)
```

Comment: Thanks, This has resolve the Partial Issue, as if there are no data on Today as well as day before yesterday then it displays only yesterday's data but want to display data of last two available dates

Comment: Is there any option where I can give the Two Max Value to compare? as i am having another DataSet with one column with 2 Dates

Comment: ok Thanks Issue resolved with this `=IIF(Fields!FieldDate.Value = (Lookup(Fields!FieldDate.Value, Fields!DATE.Value,Fields!DATE.Value , "DataSet1")), false, true)` Thanks